# pdo query not executing when passing a variable as the query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, executequery

I have a pdo command like this `$sql = $pdoObj->execute($query)` but it does not work, 0 result returning. I echo'ed out the `$query` variable just before calling `execute()` and then pasted it inside the `execute()` and the code ran successfully. I can't understand what is the problem here as I have done this in other parts of my code without problems. 
Here are some examples of the queries:

```
SELECT s.id, s.marca, s.colore, s.prezzo, i.id_scarpa, i.taglia FROM scarpe AS s INNER JOIN info_scarpe AS i ON i.id_scarpa = s.id WHERE 1 = 1 AND taglia IN ('40','41','42') AND colore IN ('rosso', 'nero')

SELECT * FROM scarpe WHERE 1=1

SELECT * FROM scarpe WHERE 1=1 AND marca IN ('adidas','nike')
```

They are all dynamic generated queries based on the `$_GET` variable.

EDIT:
Sure

```
if ( isset($_GET) ) {

                if ( isset($_GET['taglia']) ) {

                    $query = "
                            SELECT 
                                s.id, s.marca, s.colore, s.prezzo, i.id_scarpa, i.taglia
                            FROM 
                                scarpe AS s
                            INNER JOIN
                                info_scarpe AS i
                            ON i.id_scarpa = s.id
                            WHERE
                                1 = 1
                    ";
                    foreach ( $_GET as $index => $val ) {
                        $a = explode(',', $val);
                        $in =  "'" . implode("','",  $a) . "'";
                        $query .= ' AND '.$index.' IN ('.$in.')';
                    }
                } else {
                    $query = " SELECT * FROM scarpe WHERE 1=1";
                    foreach ( $_GET as $index => $val ) {
                        $a = explode(',', $val);
                        $in =  "'" . implode("','",  $a) . "'";
                        $query .= ' AND '.$index.' IN ('.$in.')';
                    }
                }
                echo 'data loaded';
            } else {
                $query = " SELECT * FROM scarpe ORDER BY id DESC ";
            }
```

EDIT2:

I use `query()` and not `execute()` but still does not work

Comment: Could you post your php code for generating the query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arguments for `execute` should be an array with query parameters.  You mean to use either

```
$result = $pdoObj->query($query);
```

OR

```
$stmt = $pdoObj->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Sorry, my main post is incorrect, I use `query()` and not `execute()`. Still, it only works when I pass the query as text and not as variable.